# Display Recent 3 Record from Django model in a HTML Template

Tags: python, django

I would like to show the latest 3 posts in the Latest Posts section of my page. How can I do it without using for loop or is that the only way?

I was successful to get the result in the shell console, however, I am not able to show it in the HTML template. Please help

## models.py

```
from typing import Any
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blogpic = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Enter a short desctiption', editable=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='banking', editable=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='consulting', editable=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, editable=True,)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
```

## views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . models import BlogPost

class BlogView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    ordering = ['-blog_date']

class BlogDetailsView(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog_details.html'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from AssayBlog.models import BlogPost
from . views import BlogView, BlogDetailsView

urlpatterns = [
     path('', BlogView.as_view(), name="blog"),
     path('_detail/<int:pk>', BlogDetailsView.as_view(), name="blog_details"),
```

## blog_details.html

```
 <h3 class="sidebar__title">Latest Posts</h3>
 <ul class="sidebar__post-list list-unstyled">
    <li>
       <div class="sidebar__post-image">
          <img src="{% static 'assets/images/blog/lp-1-1.jpg' %}" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="sidebar__post-content">
           <h3>
              <a href="#" class="sidebar__post-content_meta"><i class="far fa-comments"></i>2 Comments</a>
              <a href="news-details.html">going global with transformation</a>
           </h3>
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_context_data` funtion in any `views.py`.

```
class BlogDetailsView(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['latests_posts'] = BlogPost.objects.all()[-3:]    # or [:3] depending on model ordering
        return context
```

In template use:

```
{% for post in latest_posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    # rest of single post section
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Nixon, thanks for the response, so after adding the get_queryset() in the views.py, do I need to use for-loop in the HTML for the section I want to display?

Comment: Yes, you still got 3 objects that you want to show one after another. Wait a second, where do you want that 3 posts? In `BlogView` or `BlogDetailsView`? I've changed to universal approach via `get_context_data`.

Comment: I will be displaying the output in the blog_details.html, It worked !! only when I used [:3], it says "Negative indexing is not supported." when I used [-3]. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are right, I've forgot about it. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hi, what if, I have to display the same 3 posts in the index.html, do I need to create a view in views.py and also add URLs? not sure what to do please help.

Comment: You can add `get_context_data` in any view you want to :) Each view is individual.

Comment: so I create a new view where template_name is index.html and add the get_context_data function.  Then add a URL in the urls.py is that it.

Comment: Yes, that should work I believe. For any future issues just start new topic. Good luck! :)